# why the schema shows "group" when I haven't done "group" (hadoop pig)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Hi Here's an example from http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#describe.

Why the schema of A and B includes some "group"? I thought the schema would have "group" only after you've done a group command (like in C).

```
A = LOAD 'student' AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);

B = FILTER A BY name matches 'J.+';

C = GROUP B BY name;


DESCRIBE A;
A: {group, B: (name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float}

DESCRIBE B;
B: {group, B: (name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float}

DESCRIBE C;
C: {group, chararry,B: (name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float}
```

Comment: Did you get the same result on your machine ? Also, I noticed you linked the 0.10 release documentation. While I can't explain the difference, the current release (0.13) documentation shows what you're expecting.

Comment: (i didn't try it out because i didn't have the data...) oh i didn't notice the version of the manual! Thanks for pointing that out! @fxm